# 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found bypass via another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class where I write a theme model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'theme_preference.dart';

class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDark;
  ThemePreferences _preferences;
  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  ThemeModel(this._preferences, this._isDark) {
    _isDark = false;
    _preferences = ThemePreferences();
    getPreferences();
  }

  set isDark(bool value) {
    _isDark = value;
    _preferences.setTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  getPreferences() async {
    _isDark = await _preferences.getTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

to use the change I had to add `create: (_) => ThemeModel(this._preferences, this._isDark),`  in the main class. But when I do it so, I get an error like this: `The getter '_isDark' isn't defined for the type '_ToDoState'.` I can´t initialise the variables in the main class so my question is, if there is a way that I can cast these thinks in the other class where I initialised it?

By the way I am following this tutorial:
https://www.flutterant.com/switching-themes-in-flutter-apps/

Comment: Where does `_ToDoState` come from?

Comment: this is from the main class

Comment: So your main class is called `_ToDoState`?

Comment: no its called ToDo but is a stfull widget `lass ToDo extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ToDoState createState() => _ToDoState();
}

class _ToDoState extends State<ToDo> {`

Comment: Ok, but the error are telling you that `_ToDoState` does not have a variable called `_isDark` so `this` must in the context of `create: (_) => ThemeModel(this._preferences, this._isDark)` be your `_ToDoState` class. Does this class have access to a field called `_isDart`?

Comment: what do you mean with access? I importet the class where the field is initialized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241350/discussion-between-julemand101-and-cube-gamer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that `ThemeModel` is changed from the example in the article in an attempt to solve problems related to null-safety (the article is written before null-safety was introduced). Instead of the current `ThemeModel` it should be changed to:

```dart
class ThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDark = _false;
  ThemePreferences _preferences = ThemePreferences();
  bool get isDark => _isDark;

  ThemeModel() {
    getPreferences();
  }

  set isDark(bool value) {
    _isDark = value;
    _preferences.setTheme(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void getPreferences() async {
    _isDark = await _preferences.getTheme();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Since the example is not made for `ThemeModel` to take any arguments.

Objects in Dart are created in two phases and all non-nullable non-late variable must have a value before the constructor body is executed. By changing the code like I have done, the variables `_isDark` and `_preferences` gets initial values before the constructor body is executing `getPreferences();`.